# The maximum allowed value of a view's height?

Tags: android, view

I have a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="21474836px"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

But nothing displayed, and I changed 2147483647px to 214748364px, the text is displayed but won't scroll, and when I changed to 21474836px, everything works fine.

Can anyone explain this? what is the max value here?

**Update**: I want to use a extremely large view to achieve a semi-infinite view, and I use px instead of dp here, because I do not know if there is a limitation, whether it is expressed in px or dp?

Answer (score 1):

Some problems with this layout:

1) It is not advised to give the dimensions in `px`. Stick to `dp`.

2) You are not specified the width attributes. Did this actually compile?

3) What is the need for the `RelativeLayout`?

That said, leave it to the system to determine the required height by using `android:height="fill_parent"` or `android:height="wrap_content"`.

Comment: I agree, dp is better than px.

Comment: it is not the full code, I have irrelevant attributes deleted. The full code actually compile. I need to use a very large relativeLayout as a semi-infinite view.

Comment: it would be important to review everything in a layout file - because simple things could have very big consequences; and you wouldnt even know. Pls paste your full code.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to specify `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` together.
- For max height or width use `match_parent`, this is the preferred value, instead of `fill_parent`.  If you want tighter control of your view's dimensions you may want to consider extending the `RelativeLayout` class and overriding on onMeasure() and/or onLayout().